# Game running slow when testing in Flash Pro CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Adobe Flash CC is great and works pretty fast, but there is only one problem,

when I choose "Control - Test Movie - In Flash Professional", the game is running very slow.

If I test game in browser, then everything is fine, but I cannot see output warnings.

I did not have similar problems with Adobe Flash CS6.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug flash player has overhead that the main release version does not.  This means that the debug version of the flash player will always run a bit slower as it has added overhead.

Also, I've found the `trace()` with large amounts of data/text can really slow things down too.  If you do a lot of `trace()` statements (especially in loops or enter/exit frame handlers) that is likely what is causing your speed variation between debug and release.

As an aside, you can debug right in the browser if desired. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Download and install the flash content debug player for your browser:
   https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
2. In Flash Pro, from the debug menu, choose "Begin Remote Debug Session"
3. In your browser, right click the flash item, and choose "debug"

Comment: The game is running slow even if I do not have trace statements. I have downloaded Vizzy flash tracer, I can test game in browser and see output message in a small window (browser independent), it is an old tool I did not use before.